# BeautifulSoup find tags failed with headers

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want find a `ul` tag whose id is 'thread_list'. If I add a headers as a param to the `requests.get()` it cannot find the tag. However, if I leave out the headers, then it works.

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
       'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'
       }

url='http://tieba.baidu.com/f?kw=acu&ie=utf-8&pn=0'
```

This one didnot work(with headers and ul is None):

```
resWithHeaders=requests.get(url,headers = headers)
with open('soup1.txt','w')as f:
    f.write(resWithHeaders.text.encode('utf-8'))
soup1=BeautifulSoup(resWithHeaders.text, 'html.parser')
ul=soup1.find('ul',{'id':'thread_list'})
print ul
```

This one worked(without headers):

```
resWithoutHeaders=requests.get(url)
with open('soup2.txt','w')as f:
    f.write( resWithoutHeaders.text.encode('utf-8'))
soup2=BeautifulSoup( resWithoutHeaders.text, 'html.parser')
ul=soup2.find('ul',{'id':'thread_list'})
print ul
```

Comment: issue with `Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36` in the header  this two you remove it and try it will work

Comment: @Sunimal S.K Malkakulage Could you tell why it is  plainly or where I can know about this issue in bs4's docs?